# Unable to install mongodump

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ubuntu, mongodb-query

I have tried to install `mongodump` in Ubuntu 20:

```
brew tap mongodb/brew
```

then

```
brew install mongodb-community
```

should install `mongodump` but I get this error with second command:

> ==> Fetching mongodb/brew/mongodb-database-tools Error: mongodb-community: Failed to download resource
> "mongodb-database-tools" Failure while executing; `/usr/bin/env /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/shared/curl --disable --cookie /dev/null --globoff --show-error --user-agent Linuxbrew/4.1.7\ \(Linux\;\ x86_64\ Ubuntu\ 20.04.6\ LTS\)\ curl/7.68.0 --header Accept-Language:\ en --retry 3 --fail --location --silent --head --request GET https://fastdl.mongodb.org/tools/db/mongodb-database-tools-macos-x86_64-100.8.0.zip`
> exited with 22. Here's the output: curl: (22) The requested URL
> returned error: 403

How to fix this?

Comment: 403 is the HTTP reponse for forbidden.  Can you download that file in a browser?

Comment: Yes, I can download that file in a browser